# Android - Animations to slide between Navigation Drawer fragments

Tags: java, android, animation, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I want to be able to slide up and down between fragments based on the order they are in the navigation drawer. An example of this is what they do with Facebook Messenger where let's say I want to switch between the first tab and the fourth tab, it will go through the 1st, 2nd and 3rd tabs quickly before making it to the 4th tab. How do I replicate that kind of animation in my application. (I want mine to slide up and down however.)

MainActivity.java

```
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    NavigationView navigationView = null;
    Toolbar toolbar = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Disables Orientation throughout the entire application
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        //Set the fragment initially
        WelcomeFragment fragment = new WelcomeFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        //How to change elements in the header programatically
        View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        TextView emailText = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        emailText.setText("Scouting Application");

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    } //End of onCreate

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        } //End of if statement
    } //End of onBackPressed

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_welcome) {
            //Set the fragment initially
            WelcomeFragment fragment = new WelcomeFragment();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            // Handle the camera action
        }
        else if (id == R.id.nav_facebook) {
            FacebookFragment fragment = new FacebookFragment();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
        else if (id == R.id.nav_scout) {
            //Set the fragment initially
            ScoutFragment fragment = new ScoutFragment();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
        else if (id == R.id.nav_match) {
            //Set the fragment initially
            MatchFragment fragment = new MatchFragment();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    } //End of onNavigationItemSelected
} //End of class
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a library which can make those kind of animations. I am looking same kind of transition effects and this might be helpful to you.

[FragmentTransactionExtended](https://github.com/DesarrolloAntonio/FragmentTransactionExtended)

also another code here:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

switch(id) {
    // ...

    // up button
    case android.R.id.home:
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_back_in, R.anim.activity_back_out);
        return true;
}

return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```